# Dequeing existing object from the Queue returns null

Tags: c#, message-queue, nservicebus

I have a WPF app where I use MVVM and it also uses NServicebus.
I have a BusHandler class inherited from IHandleMessages which is responsible for receiving the messages from NServicebus.
Now, when I receive the message I need to assign it to some value of my ViewModel and raise some event to notify my VIewModel that the value was updated and now needs to be processed.
For this purpose I created the standard MS Queue object and added to the Queue OnChange event. The Queue object is static so that I could access it from BusHandler. So the logic is: BusHandler receives the message from NServicebus, places the message into the static Queue object, this enqueue method raises OnChange event and my processing method knows that value was updated and needs to be processed.
Now the strange part:
Before extracting the object from the queue I check whether my Queue contains anything:

```
if(Queue.Count>0)
{
var obj = Queue.Dequeue();
...
}
```

And this is where the bad magic starts:
In most of the cases I successfully receive the object, but in some cases the if condition says that the Queue contains something (and it's true) but dequeueing returns me null.

Why is that and how can I resolve it?
And maybe there is a better way to communicate with the ViewModel from the Handler class?

Comment: is this multithreaded application?

Comment: @J.Doe do you have multiple queue consumers? If there are two consumers (threads) that consume messages from the queue it could occur, that the first consumer checks the count and before dequeing the other consumer already dequeues. In this case you either have to lock the code snippet shown in the description or you make use of ConcurrentQueue.

Comment: No, there is only 1 single consumer - the ViewModel

Comment: Is it possible that a null reference was pushed on the queue?

Comment: No, the null reference can not be pushed to the queue

Comment: Also there is a strange behaviour of the debugger when I debug: it starts from checking the condition if Queue has values. Then it goes to the next line where I am trying to dequeue, then it goes back to the condition line and then it goes back again to the line where I am dequeueing...it's weird

Comment: I think you have a mixed set of concerns and responsibilities here. You're using NSB as well as MSMQ which NSB abstracts away, so kind of beats the purpose. Also for your ViewModel notification why do you go through a queue? IMO only 'business data' that require persistence to disk would have to go through the queue and the UI events and notification should be done via a UI event aggregator.

Also NSB is multi-threaded. By the time you check if there's any message on the queue, another thread might have consumed it already, which is probably why you get null back.

Comment: No, I don't use MSMQ except of the NSB which uses MSMQ. When I said Queue, I referred to the MS Queue class from System.Collection which does not use any MSMQ

Comment: And there is no other thread